# iTunes restore error 4014

Tags: macos, ipad, itunes, restore, ipados

My iPad Pro (model with home button and not Face ID) has a blank screen always.

I can’t wake it - holding down power+home buttons does not force a reboot, nor does holding volume buttons and power button.

When plugged into iTunes, it reports that the iPad needs to be restored. The iPad is detected with Serial Number as n/a.

[image]

When I proceed to restore the iPad, iTunes prepares the files, and tries to restore the device.

But then I get Error 4014.

[image]

System log is below:

```
default 09:31:59.590611 -0700   iTunes  TCP Conn 0x60000036ef40 event 1. err: 0
default 09:31:59.590923 -0700   iTunes  TCP Conn 0x60000036ef40 complete. fd: 39, err: 0
default 09:31:59.591126 -0700   iTunes  TCP Conn 0x60000036ef40 starting SSL negotiation
default 09:31:59.594592 -0700   icdd    #ICDebug - 205:{ICResourceManager.m} (43504944-3A38-3031-3120-435052563A31|Apple Mobile Device (DFU Mode)|MANUFACTURER:Apple Inc.;MODEL:Apple Mobile Device (DFU Mode)|SW=FALSE|)
default 09:31:59.595456 -0700   icdd    #ICDebug - 457:{ICDDMessageCenter.m} (+Add Apple Mobile Device (DFU Mode) - 0x0/0x0/0x0 - 0x14100000 - ICDeviceDescriptionInferior)
default 09:31:59.608164 -0700   iTunes  TCP Conn 0x60000036ef40 SSL Handshake DONE
default 09:31:59.643858 -0700   iTunes  TCP Conn 0x60000036ef40 canceled
default 09:31:59.644125 -0700   iTunes  [65 <private> stream, pid: 394] cancelled
    [65.1 C62BF7BF-9D59-44F4-AEE5-0835F0416D38 <private>.49430<-><private>]
    Connected Path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns
    Duration: 0.128s, DNS @0.000s took 0.059s, TCP @0.060s took 0.015s
    bytes in/out: 1543/1063, packets in/out: 4/5, rtt: 0.014s, retransmitted packets: 0, out-of-order packets: 0
default 09:31:59.652092 -0700   MobileDeviceUpdater Known, supported, and restorable device. Continuing...
default 09:32:01.001261 -0700   iTunes  tid:27a1b - iTunes: Restore error 4014
```

I also see this line, which I think could be telling:

**iTunes    tid:21b1b - Unexpected device state 'DFU' expected 'RestoreOS'**

Anything else I can do with this out-of-warranty iPad other than disposing of it?

Answer (score 1):

**Three findings:**

- Apple Genius Bar is not able to fix an error 4014 other than a hardware repair on the iPad.
- Third party software Fixppo by imyfone cannot fix the error either, and worse: they do not honour their "Money Back Guarantee". So don't bother with them.
- Apple charges c$579 + tax for a replacement, what is effectively a 4 year old device.